# How does it work? - Javascript function to make non-IE fixes using YUI

Tags: javascript, dom, yui

Here's the code I'm trying to understand:

noniefix.js:

```
function fixNonIE() {
if(YAHOO.env.ua.ie > 0) {
    return false;
}
var divs = YAHOO.util.Dom.get('bd').getElementsByTagName('div');
if(divs.length > 0) {
    YAHOO.util.Dom.batch(divs, pushup);
    alert (divs.length+" divs in file!");
}
}

function pushup(el) {
if(el.id.search('fixer') != -1) {
    return;
}
if(el.innerHTML.search('javascript:textWindow') != -1) {
    el.style.zIndex = parseInt(el.style.zIndex) + 1;
}
var pushupTags = Array('p');
if(pushupTags.length > 0) {
    for(var t=0; t<pushupTags.length; t++) {
        var elems = el.getElementsByTagName(pushupTags[t]);
        YAHOO.util.Dom.batch(elems, (function(e) { e.style.marginTop=0; e.style.marginBottom=0; })); //what's happening HERE?
    }
}
return;
}
```

I've read up a bit on YUI, so I know that the batch function just takes an array of elements and applies the function to each element. What I don't understand is where the marginTop, marginBottom changes are applied. I think they are applied to each `<p>` tag, but I've viewed the source code of the page and can't find where this code is being inserted.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you edit your post, now the tag is eaten by my browser (just put backticks around the `<p>`). Actually, you mean `<p>` elements, on which the changes are applied. You cannot see a change when viewing a pages source, because that file will not be changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see result of this function at the source code because it appplys dynamicly by JS to the each DOM tag written in array. But you can see the changes using some debugger software, builded in Internet Explorer 8 for example, or firebug under Mozilla Firefox.